# How to check that multiple Outlook dialogues aren't being created for same Email/Filename?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, outlook-2007

I am using C#.NET in VS2010. In my below code I check each record in a datagrid for having been selected for Reporting. If selected, I then check each of the 3 available contact fields to see if that entity needs to be contacted by having the generated report emailed to them.

Filenames are saved as “IN_MUL_*BusinessID_Date_Time_ContactPoint*”, ex. “IN_MUL_25_05202013_09.11.14_BUS”. If I select 2 test results to report from the same Sample#, meaning they have the same ContactResults structure on their Account, 2 email dialogues open to the same person, with the same report attached. In this situation, the code is processing correctly, but logically I only need the one dialogue as it's the same report to the same individual.

Does anyone know of a fairly easy way I could check if a dialogue to a person and with a particular attachment has already been created, and if so, ignore that processing?

My code is below:

```
private void emailReports()
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow recRow in dgvTests.Rows)
            {
                if (((recRow.Cells["Select"].Value != null) && Boolean.Parse(recRow.Cells["Select"].Value.ToString())))
                {
                    // If Business should be contacted with Sample Test Results
                    if ((recRow.Cells["BusinessContactResults"].Value != null) && (Boolean.Parse(recRow.Cells["BusinessContactResults"].Value.ToString()) == true) && (recRow.Cells["BusinessEmail"].Value != null))
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
                        mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)objApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                        mail.To = recRow.Cells["BusinessEmail"].Value.ToString();
                        mail.Subject = "Inspection Notification";
                        mail.Body = "";
                        mail.Attachments.Add((object)string.Format("{0}IN_{1}_{2}_{3}_BUS.pdf", reptLoc, strLSN, recRow.Cells["BusinessID"].Value, dtString), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, (object)"Attachment");
                        mail.Display();
                    }
                    if ((recRow.Cells["SupplierContactResults"].Value != null) && (Boolean.Parse(recRow.Cells["SupplierContactResults"].Value.ToString()) == true) && (recRow.Cells["SupplierEmail"].Value != null))
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
                        mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)objApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                        mail.To = recRow.Cells["SupplierEmail"].Value.ToString();
                        mail.Subject = "Inspection Notification";
                        mail.Body = "";
                        mail.Attachments.Add((object)string.Format("{0}IN_{1}_{2}_{3}_SUP.pdf", reptLoc, strLSN, recRow.Cells["BusinessID"].Value, dtString), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, (object)"Attachment");
                        mail.Display();
                    }
                    if ((recRow.Cells["CorporateContactResults"].Value != null) && (Boolean.Parse(recRow.Cells["CorporateContactResults"].Value.ToString()) == true) && (recRow.Cells["CorporateEmail"].Value != null))
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
                        mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)objApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                        mail.To = recRow.Cells["CorporateEmail"].Value.ToString();
                        mail.Subject = "Inspection Notification";
                        mail.Body = "";
                        mail.Attachments.Add((object)string.Format("{0}IN_{1}_{2}_{3}_CRP.pdf", reptLoc, strLSN, recRow.Cells["BusinessID"].Value, dtString), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, (object)"Attachment");
                        mail.Display();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to remember the dialogs already processed. Store a concatenation of recipient, separator character (eg '~') and attachment as `HashSet` item. Use the `Contains()` method to find if the current combination has been there already.

By the way:

In your code you could use the following statement:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

This allows you to use `Outlook` rather than the lengthy `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` to shorten your code and clean it up.

The code could look like this:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace nsXYZ
{
    class AClass
    {
        private void emailReports()
        {
            HashSet<String> diaSet = new HashSet<String>();
            Outlook.Application objApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
            String s;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow recRow in dgvTests.Rows)
            {
                if (((recRow.Cells["Select"].Value != null) && Boolean.Parse(recRow.Cells["Select"].Value.ToString())))
                {
                    mail = null;

                    // If Business should be contacted with Sample Test Results
                    if ((recRow.Cells["BusinessContactResults"].Value != null) && (Boolean.Parse(recRow.Cells["BusinessContactResults"].Value.ToString()) == true) && (recRow.Cells["BusinessEmail"].Value != null))
                    {
                        mail = (Outlook.MailItem)objApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                        mail.To = recRow.Cells["BusinessEmail"].Value.ToString();
                        mail.Attachments.Add((object)string.Format("{0}IN_{1}_{2}_{3}_BUS.pdf", reptLoc, strLSN, recRow.Cells["BusinessID"].Value, dtString), Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, (object)"Attachment");
                    }
                    if ((recRow.Cells["SupplierContactResults"].Value != null) && (Boolean.Parse(recRow.Cells["SupplierContactResults"].Value.ToString()) == true) && (recRow.Cells["SupplierEmail"].Value != null))
                    {
                        mail = (Outlook.MailItem)objApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                        mail.To = recRow.Cells["SupplierEmail"].Value.ToString();
                        mail.Attachments.Add((object)string.Format("{0}IN_{1}_{2}_{3}_SUP.pdf", reptLoc, strLSN, recRow.Cells["BusinessID"].Value, dtString), Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, (object)"Attachment");
                    }
                    if ((recRow.Cells["CorporateContactResults"].Value != null) && (Boolean.Parse(recRow.Cells["CorporateContactResults"].Value.ToString()) == true) && (recRow.Cells["CorporateEmail"].Value != null))
                    {
                        mail = (Outlook.MailItem)objApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                        mail.To = recRow.Cells["CorporateEmail"].Value.ToString();
                        mail.Attachments.Add((object)string.Format("{0}IN_{1}_{2}_{3}_CRP.pdf", reptLoc, strLSN, recRow.Cells["BusinessID"].Value, dtString), Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, (object)"Attachment");
                    }

                    if ((mail != null) && !diaSet.Contains(s = mail.To + "~" + mail.Attachments[0]))
                    {
                        diaSet.Add(s);
                        mail.Subject = "Inspection Notification";
                        mail.Body = "";
                        mail.Display();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Axel! If I can get that to work, it sounds like it would fit the bill to solve my issue. Is there anyway you could point me to some good examples or help me with writing out what is needed? I've never used HashSet before, and the MSDN page has me a little overwhelmed.

Comment: Scratch that, I got it figured out! Thanks so much!